# How to install Minecraft from local files so that downloading the game gets replaced by the already downloaded files from another installation?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows

I want to install Minecraft Java Edition on more than one computer and do not see why I should download the full game for each installation.

How can I take the first installation's downloaded files as the files for other installations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the installation's Minecraft folder, just enter `%appdata%` in the Explorer and you will be in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming`. There, you should see the folder:

`.minecraft`

The dot at the beginning of the folder name means that it is hidden, if you do not see the folder, switch on to see hidden files in the settings of the explorer.

Copy the hidden folder to a stick or whatever so that you can paste them for the other installations.

Afterwards, on a new computer that shall install Minecraft, copy the hidden folder to `%appdata%` and once that is done, run the installer.